# Security Error in Intellij when running TomCat

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

When i want to run a tomcat in Intellij i get error bellow every 10s and localhost:8080 doesn't show anything. can anyone help me?

> WARNING - "null OEJP/4.6" FAIL "Security error - [Ljava.net.URI; is not whitelisted as deserialisable, prevented before loading it, customize tomee.serialization.class.blacklist and tomee.serialization.class.whitelist to add it to not fail there. -Dtomee.serialization.class.blacklist=- -Dtomee.serialization.class.whitelist=[Ljava.net.URI; for instance (or in conf/system.properties)." - Debug for StackTrace

Answer (score 0):

I really don't remember the exact steps that i take to solve this problem but i can say i understood that error has kind of relation with artifacts of my spring project with intellij, and after adding the bellow parts to my pom.xml and make maven to autoImport needed things, then creating new artifact inside creating new tomCat server, the problem was all gone.

I add these tag after groupID, artifactID, and version

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>AnyName</name>
```

and then these lines to the end of the pom:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>Example</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>Example</finalName>
</build>
```